# Angular - $location.path('/login').replace() not working even after $scope.$apply()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Below is my code
HTML

```
<div class="buttons ">
    <div class="logout" ></div>
    <div class="tip" >Logout</div>
</div>
```

Route Configuration

```
 var app = angular.module("myapp", ['ngRoute']);
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'login.html',
        controller: 'loginController'
    }).when('/main', {
        templateUrl: 'main.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
    }).otherwise({redirectTo: '/login'});
}]);
```

At Controller:

```
 $scope.logout = function(){
    $location.path('/login').replace();
    $scope.$apply();
}
$('#logout').parent().click(function(){
    $scope.logout();
});
$('.logout').click(function(){
    $scope.logout();
});
```

Though my location is getting changed at URL level, my UI is not getting rendered even after using **$scope.$apply()**. It is expecting a **reload()**. 
I have also tried

```
$scope.logout = function(){
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $location.path('/login').replace();
    });
}
```

and even if I use **ng-click = "logout()"** same behaviour. No UI is rendered.

Can any one please help me out in this?

---

Comment: are you using ui-router? make sure it doesn't post any error event

Comment: Do you have any logic to change your UI based on the path (ie, a router)? FYI, `replace()` does not reload anything. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#replace

Comment: @Bryan, am not using ui-router.

Comment: $stateprovider or $routeprovider in your app.js?

Comment: yes Conrad, am using **$routeprovider**

Comment: I definitely would **not** use `replace()`

Comment: I havent used replace() for reload. even if i remove replace(), same behaviour :(

Comment: How are you calling `$scope.logout()`?

Comment: That doesn't tell us anything. Do you even have an element with class "logout"? Have you even included jQuery? Does that bit of script have access to `$scope.logout`? Why not just use `ng-click="logout()"`?

Comment: check, if you have forgotten to use ng-controller in your view?

Comment: omg, Shailendra, if i dont have there wont be any navigation at all. for your query, I have ng-controller in my view.

Comment: **Have you included jQuery**? Did you check your console for errors?

Comment: Did you see changes of your url in browser bar ?